# Performance counters on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, performance, performancecounter

I'm trying to find the best method of incode performance monitoring on the iPhone.

On a windows platform I would use the following functions :

QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *)&ctr);
QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER *)&freq);

Does anything like this exist on the iPhone? Whats the highest resolution I can time something without using an external tool such as Instruments or Shark?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think mach_absolute_time is what you are looking for. For more information:

- [Technical Q&A QA1398: Mach Absolute Time Units](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1398/_index.html)
- [Tutorial: Performance and Time](http://www.macresearch.org/tutorial_performance_and_time)
- [mach_ absolute_ time on the iPhone](http://shiftedbits.org/2008/10/01/mach_absolute_time-on-the-iphone/)